# Cannot correctly parse a CSV delimited by commas, but containing a header, and with fields surrounded by double quotes, but which also contain commas

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv

I've had a search around, and found some solutions which should work, but for some reason just aren't working for me. Here is the sample CSV i'm working with:

```
"Org. Code","Hubspot Ref","Company Name","Contact First Name","Contact Last Name","Job Title","Address","City","Phone","Email","Last Update"
"2h34h234h","12345678","A Random Company","John","Smith","Developer","300 PARK AVE SOUTH, 4TH FL","NEW YORK","+123456789","john.smith@random.org","10/03/2016 12:00"
```

I'm trying to parse it with this snippet of code:

```
with open(os.path.basename(theCSV),"r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    data = list(reader)

    for row in range(0, len(data)):
```

This is currently doing two undesirable things: **1)** Its reading the header row, and **2)** The comma in the address field is being interpreted as a delimiter instead of part of the field value.

Now, research on SO has shown me that what I'm doing above, should be reworked into something like this:

```
with open(os.path.basename(theCSV),"r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    next(reader)

    for row in reader:
```

This throws an error: `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not list`. I then tried to work my way around the `TypeError` and first line issue with this:

```
with open(os.path.basename(theCSV),"r") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    data = list(reader)
    outRange = len(data) + 1

    for row in range(1, outRange):
```

This still runs into the comma in the field value as a delimiter, not to mention that its probably not very pythonic, or robust. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not able to replicate your issue, the default `csv.reader` properly handles quotes and doesn't split on internal `,` for me. Can you show the complete error (e.g. the line it occurs on) and/or output. You can use a `csv.DictReader` to automatically handle the header and return a dict per row.

Comment: why not just use pandas? `pd.DataFrame.from_csv(THECSV)`

Comment: Thanks @AChampion - I managed to fix it - my issue was that I was relying on [CSVMapper](https://github.com/samarjeet27/CSV-Mapper) to map the csv - as soon as I took it out, and referred to indexes in the row correctly (like using `row[9]` for example) it started working.